# jTextField validation for numbers and strings?

Tags: java, validation, textbox

I want to set my own validation for textfield in java. For an instance, lets say i want user to enter values like  **10d2-5**, **100d2**,**23d5** , and not like**aa25-22**. I could do this using MaskFormatter but the problem is that if i set its format to (##d#) it won't  accept three digit numbers. Here's my code:

```
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();
MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##.#");
dateMask.install(textField);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a  InputVerifier example which should get you started:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
      {

          JTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();
          textField.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
      }
}

class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

      public MyInputVerifier() {}

      @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {

        JTextField textField = (JTextField) input;
        String validate = textField.getText();
          if (validate !=null /* replace with relevant tests cosde */) {

              return true;
          } else {

              return false;
          }
      }
  }
```